# SEVERE: CouchDBQuery error. java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: apache, tomcat, couchdb, httpclient, socketexception

When i try to connect to couchdb I get this error. Can someone tell me the reasons why this is happening. Do I have to assign null to HttpClient and GetMethod in a method which is calling couchdb?

```
SEVERE: CouchDBQuery error
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:397)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:371)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:249)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception means there are not enough file handles to open sockets on your machine. How to check this on Linux and Windows is [here](http://amitbhayani.blogspot.in/2010/01/javanetsocketexception-too-many-open.html).

With HTTPClient, it's recommended to use one of the connection managers available to ensure shutting down of connections.

See Sec 2.8 of this guide on how to use [HTTPClient connection manager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)